# Jenkins behind a Proxy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've to perform an HTTP post of an artifact (Jenkins build) to an Internet website. Nevertheless my Company has got a proxy in front of Jenkins.
Does anybody know how to authenticate against an http proxy during a Jenkins task ?
Thanks and Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following lines in execute shell  field of **Post-build Actions** :-

```
curl -x <proxy_host:proxy_port> -X POST <url_of_website> --data-binary <your_artifact_location>
```